# Is there a LEGO podcast?

Tags: popular-culture

I have tried to find a podcast about LEGO but haven't found any currently active. There seems to be some old ones out there with a couple of episodes, but nothing new that I could find.

Anyone knows any?

Comment: All Sorted is the only one I could find.

Answer (score 5):

The All Us Geeks podcast regularly has a segment on LEGO called the Brick Breakdown that is run by William and Sarah Reed. Here is the link to the latest episode (scroll down to see when the Brick Breakdown section starts): http://www.allusgeeks.com/2015/08/episode-60-dead-men-tell-no-tales/

My guess is that because LEGO is so hands-on and so visual, it is kind of hard to run a fully dedicated podcast about it. William and his wife mainly talk about things like the history of LEGO, investing in LEGO, etc. That's pretty much all you can do through a podcast.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond The Brick was a podcast that featured interviews with AFOLs and reports on Lego-related news. Although they have since moved to a video format on YouTube, their current interview content is very similar to their old podcasts:
https://www.youtube.com/user/BeyondTheBrickTV/

There are a couple more-specialized podcasts that are active:

ttvpodcast (Bionicle)

http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/inside-dimensions (Lego Dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

LAMLradio was a long running LEGO podcast: http://lamlradio.com/ They stopped updating it in 2012, sadly.

Comment: Yes, I have heard a couple of those episodes. They were OK.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes! I will make a proper answer out of the comment by @GreenBaron80J11.*

I have not found any other pod thats alive than [All Sorted](http://www.breakingdads.com/category/all-sorted/). But after backtracking a couple episodes I would say its a supernice pod. Go listen, I certainly will :-)